# JavaScript Adding and Multiplying

Tags: javascript

Without changing this function:

```
function operate(operator, operand1, operand2) {
    return operator(operand1, operand2);
}
```

I want to write out:

```
var x = operator(add, operate(add, 2, 3), operate(multiply, 4, 5));
```

And get 25 as a value of x. How can I do this?

Comment: You do that by changing the function ?

Comment: I can't do it without changing the operate function?

Comment: This is homework? ...Yes? No?

Comment: are you allowed to add to the function? maybe you can link your operate function to another function? could you give us more details on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: The solution is simple enough. I'd just hate to do someone's homework for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being that `operator` is expected to be a function, but execution requires `add` and `multiply` to be defined as:

```
function add(x,y) {
    return x + y;
}

function multiply(x,y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

Also, I think there's a typo:

```
ReferenceError: operator is not defined
```

I would have:

```
var x = operate(add, operate(add, 2, 3), operate(multiply, 4, 5));
```

This gives `x = 25`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, `operator` should be `operate` in:

```
var x = operate(add, operate(add, 2, 3), operate(multiply, 4, 5));
```

You then need to define `add` and `multiply` to be 2 functions that each take 2 arguments and return the result of the 2 arguments with the appropriate operation performed.

Answer (score 0):

here you can just create two functions named on the operatorors you are using "add" and "multiply" as javascipt allow function passing in arguments your problem is solved

```
function add(x,y) {
    return x + y;
}

function multiply(x,y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

PS:you have a typo here "var x = operator(add, operate(add, 2, 3), operate(multiply, 4, 5));"
operator here is operate .